# Update Database Based On Dynamic HTML Table Input Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, database

I have a dynamic HTML table that can be edited in multiple ways. There is an edit button where you can edit inline, the information of the rows and then click save to save the information. A deactivate button that grays out the row and an activate button that appears afterwards in order to reactivate it. And also and add row button that brings up a dialog box where you can hit add row again and add another row to the table.

However, while that is all nice...I want to write these changes/updates to a SQL Server database now so it actually saves them. I want to be able to automatically save these changes after each action (save, deactivate/activate, and add row) happens. I want an UPDATE query for when the Save button is clicked and an INSERT query to run after the Add Row button in the form is clicked. I have some Ajax now but it doesn't work. I have all the necessary code to focus on the add row button writing to the DB for now. I have never done anything like this before so any help/advice/code would be appreciated!

HTML/PHP code:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>

    <input type="button" class="create-user" value="Add Row">

</table>
</div>
```

JavaScript and ajax for dialog box:

```
// ----- Dialog Box -----

$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );

      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val() );
        });
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );





$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var mr_name = $("#mr_name").val();
var buyer_id = $("#buyer_id").val();
var poc_n = $("#poc_n").val();
var poc_e = $("#poc_e").val();
var poc_p = $("#poc_p").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'mr_name1='+ mr_name + '&buyer_id1='+ buyer_id + '&poc_n1='+ poc_n + '&poc_e1='+ poc_e + '&poc_p1='+ poc_p;
if(mr_name==''||buyer_id==''||poc_n==''||poc_e==''||poc_p=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Ajax Submit code:

```
<?php

$host="xxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
// Establishing Connection with Server..

//Fetching Values from URL
$mr_name2=$_POST['mr_name1'];
$buyer_id2=$_POST['buyer_id1'];
$poc_n2=$_POST['poc_n1'];
$poc_e2=$_POST['poc_e1'];
$poc_p2=$_POST['poc_p1'];

//Insert query
$query = pdo_query("INSERT into Stage_Rebate_Master(mr_name, buyer_id, poc_n, poc_e, poc_p) values ('$mr_name2', '$buyer_id2', '$poc_n2','$poc_e2', '$poc_p2')");
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
pdo_close($dbh); // Connection Closed

?>
```